# Reading content from iframe from the outside using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have 2 HTML documents: 1 main document which has an iframe displaying the second HTML page within.

I want access the contents of the iframe from the parent document. I've tried using `find()` and `contents()`, but it is not working for me.

This is my code:

**main document**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="./js/gjquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#123').click(function(){
 alert("Testing...");
 var v = $('#frameDemo').contents().find('body').html();
 alert(v);
});
})
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="123" >mad</button>
  <iframe src="./1.htm" width="80%" height="20%" id='frameDemo'></iframe> 
</body>
```

**iframe document**

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<p>Hello <a href="http://ejohn.org/">John</a>, how are you doing?</p>

<table width="700" border="1" id="test"> 
<tr><td>g</td><td>ggg</td></tr>
<tr><td>g</td><td>ggg</td></tr>
<tr><td>g</td><td>ggg</td></tr>
</table>

<p>Hello world!</p>
<div id="someID">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`find()` does not return any results, regardless of which selector I try.

Comment: I see typo `/js/gjquery.js`. And console is your friend, start using it

Comment: Can you see your 'Testing' alert?

Comment: Yes... Even display ing another alert.. But it comes undefined

Comment: Same-domain policy? Do you get an error in Firebug concerning "permission denied"?

Comment: No such in Firefox.. works perfect with Firefox... but not with the Google chrome..

Answer (score 1):

Selecting elements within an iframe should work fine as long as both html pages are hosted on the **same domain**. I tried your code and it worked fine for me.

However, if the page in the iframe is hosted on a **different domain**, the outer frame won't have access to the inner frame due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

If this is the case, you will see an error in the console similar to this one:

"**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.bing.com/ from frame with URL localhost/jqueryIframe/jqueryIframe.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**"

Comment: I get "undefined" message on second alert.. I  just tested using chrome browser..

Comment: Can you try 'alert($("#frameDemo").contents().length);'. For me, this is 1 if it's the same domain or 0 if it's a different domain.

Comment: it is 1 in Firefox and 0 in Google chrome.. Even i got answer in Firefox , but undefined in Google chrome..

Comment: My problem is to get cell content of table inside iframe, and to find total of some cells outside the iframe.. iframe loads documents which contains table with marks.. i want to find the total... can i get the cell data when the cell is clicked ???

Comment: Can you also alert out the following two urls and check they're on the same domain: 'document.getElementById("frameDemo").src' and window.location

Comment: Yes i getting alert with the proper urls...
     alert("Testing...");
     alert($("#frameDemo").contents().length);
     alert(document.getElementById("frameDemo").src);
     alert(window.location);
     var v = $('#frameDemo').contents().find('td').html();
     alert(v);

but last alert is undefined.. please help me. [ in google chrome, works fine with firefox]